# Should I use special Unicode characters for punctuation marks such as ellipsis in programs?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, unicode, user-interface

Unicode has a set of characters for punctuation such as *ellipsis* (…), En-Dash (–) and others. It's believed that using these characters improves typography and therefore visual appearance of the texts.

Many development tools, Visual Studio included, support Unicode and so I could easily make use of these characters in programs resources - dialogs, etc.

Are there any reasons for not doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain that the users' machines will have the fonts needed to display those characters properly (and e.g. for dialogs on Windows you should definitely be able to rely on that), then, go right ahead!

Answer (score 1):

To be completely safe, I'd avoid using Unicode characters in source code files such as using them in hard-coded strings.  Instead, I'd stick with ASCII or the system code page.  The reason is that some source code management systems may not support Unicode.

For example, Tortise SVN once improperly handled a Unicode source code file and ended up permanently mangling the file beyond repair when committed, which wasn't detected until the next time it was retrieved for editing.  I think the problem occurred when the system attempted to merge changes in the new Unicode file into the originally committed non-Unicode file.  Anyway, I had to completely rewrite the code, as the mangling occurred in such a way that the original information was irrecoverable.  I don't know why it happened, or how likely it is to happen now, but I'm mentioning it because I've experienced it.

If you do avoid using Unicode in source code files, then you can store Unicode strings in embedded resources, external encoded files with proper BOMs, or databases.